# Conversion of years and months to months with string column input python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

dataset example:

```
experience

5 month
nan
1 months
8 month
17 months
8 year
11 years
1.7 year
3.1 years
15.7 months
18 year
2017.2 years
98.3 years
68 year
```

I have a column with applicant's experience in years. It is very messy and I tried to go through it and create a sample. I have numbers followed by (month or months) and (year of years).

There are many nan entries and it should be ignored.

The goal is to create a column experience in months:

```
if nan
  copy nan to the corresponding column
if the row has month or months 
  copy the number to the corresponding column
if year or years in the row and the number <55 
  the number shall be multiplied by 12 and copied to the corresponding column
else copy nan to the corresponding column
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'Experience': ['5 month', 'nan', '1 months', '8 month','17 months','8 year',
                          '11 years','1.7 year', '3.1 years', '15.7 months','18 year',
                          '2017.2 years', '98.3 years', '68 year']}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

# Create filter for month/months
month_filt = df['Experience'].str.contains('month')

# Filter DataFrame for rows that contain month/months 
df['Months'] = df.loc[month_filt, 'Experience'].str.strip('month|months')

# Create filter for year/years
year_filt = df['Experience'].str.contains('year')

# Filter DataFrame for rows that contain year/years
df['Years'] = df.loc[year_filt, 'Experience'].str.strip('year|years')

# Fill NaN in Years column
df.loc[df['Years'].isna(),'Years'] = np.nan

# Convert Years to months
df.loc[df['Months'].isna(),'Months'] = df['Years'].astype('float') * 12

# Set years greater than 55 to NaN
df.loc[df['Years'].astype('float') > 55, 'Months'] = np.nan

    Experience  Months  Years
0   5 month     5       NaN
1   nan         NaN     NaN
2   1 months    1       NaN
3   8 month     8       NaN
4   17 months   17      NaN
5   8 year      96      8
6   11 years    132     11
7   1.7 year    20.4    1.7
8   3.1 years   37.2    3.1
9   15.7 months 15.7    NaN
10  18 year     216     18
11  2017.2 yearsNaN 2017.2
12  98.3 years  NaN     98.3
13  68 year     NaN     68
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using reg expressions,  keeping workings for transparency.

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""experience

5 month
nan
1 months
8 month
17 months
8 year
11 years
1.7 year
3.1 years
15.7 months
18 year
2017.2 years
98.3 years
68 year"""))

df = df.assign(unit=lambda dfa: dfa["experience"].str.extract("([a-z]+)+"),
         val=lambda dfa: dfa["experience"].str.extract("([0-9,\.]+)").astype(float),
         months=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["unit"].isin(["month","months"]), dfa["val"],
                                    np.where(dfa["unit"].isin(["year","years"])
                                             &dfa["val"].lt(55), dfa["val"]*12, np.nan)))

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

### output

```
   experience    unit     val  months
      5 month   month     5.0     5.0
          NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
     1 months  months     1.0     1.0
      8 month   month     8.0     8.0
    17 months  months    17.0    17.0
       8 year    year     8.0    96.0
     11 years   years    11.0   132.0
     1.7 year    year     1.7    20.4
    3.1 years   years     3.1    37.2
  15.7 months  months    15.7    15.7
      18 year    year    18.0   216.0
 2017.2 years   years  2017.2     NaN
   98.3 years   years    98.3     NaN
      68 year    year    68.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes the formatting is consistent (value, space, time period). You can use split to get the two parts.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'experience': ['5 month', np.nan, '1 months', '8 month', '17 months', '8 year', '11 years']})

def get_values(x):
    if pd.notnull(x):
        val = int(x.split(' ')[0])
        prd = x.split(' ')[1]
        if prd in ['month', 'months']:
            return val
        elif prd in ['year', 'years'] and val < 55: 
            return val * 12
    else:
        return x

df['months'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_values(x.experience), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  experience  months
0    5 month     5.0
1        NaN     NaN
2   1 months     1.0
3    8 month     8.0
4  17 months    17.0
5     8 year    96.0
6   11 years   132.0
```

If there are a high percentage of NaN, you can filter first before running the lambda function

df[df.experience.notnull()].apply(lambda x: get_values(x.experience), axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a nicer way to do this using panda data frames but is this what you are trying to achieve?  You can probably use the regex if nothing else.  I've not added the condition for < 55 years but I'm sure you can work that out.

```
import re
applicants = []

applicant1 = {'name': 'Lisa', 'experience': 'nan'}
applicant2 = {'name': 'Bill', 'experience': '3.1 months'}
applicant3 = {'name': 'Mandy', 'experience': '1 month'}
applicant4 = {'name': 'Geoff', 'experience': '6.7 years'}
applicant5 = {'name': 'Patricia', 'experience': '1 year'}
applicant6 = {'name': 'Kirsty', 'experience': '2017.2 years'}

applicants.append(applicant1)
applicants.append(applicant2)
applicants.append(applicant3)
applicants.append(applicant4)
applicants.append(applicant5)
applicants.append(applicant6)

print(applicants)

month_pattern = '^([\d]+[\.\d]*) month(s*)'
year_pattern = '^([\d]+[\.\d]*) year(s*)'

applicant_output = []

for applicant in applicants:
    if applicant['experience'] == 'nan':
        applicant_output.append(applicant)
    else:
        month = re.search(month_pattern, applicant['experience'])
        if month is not None:
            applicant_output.append(
                {
                    'name': applicant['name'],
                    "exprience_months": month.group(1)
                })
        else:
            year = re.search(year_pattern, applicant['experience'])
            if year is not None:
                months = str(float(year.group(1)) * 12)
                applicant_output.append(
                    {
                        'name': applicant['name'],
                        "exprience_months": months
                    })

print(applicant_output)
```

This gives the output:

```
[{'name': 'Lisa', 'experience': 'nan'}, {'name': 'Bill', 'experience': '3.1 months'}, {'name': 'Mandy', 'experience': '1 month'}, {'name': 'Geoff', 'experience': '6.7 years'}, {'name': 'Patricia', 'experience': '1 year'}, {'name': 'Kirsty', 'experience': '2017. years'}]
```

with the result:

```
[{'name': 'Lisa', 'experience': 'nan'}, {'name': 'Bill', 'exprience_months': '3.1'}, {'name': 'Mandy', 'exprience_months': '1'}, {'name': 'Geoff', 'exprience_months': '80.4'}, {'name': 'Patricia', 'exprience_months': '12.0'}, {'name': 'Kirsty', 'exprience_months': '24206.4'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp_df` to sepearate out month/year part

```
temp_df = df['experience'].str.split('([A-Za-z]+)', expand=True)
temp_df = temp_df.loc[:, ~(temp_df == "").any(axis=0)]  # deleting the extra column coming upon split
temp_df[0] = temp_df[0].astype(float)
temp_df
```

[image]

Getting the multiplier for experince value

```
multiplier = pd.Series([1] * len(temp_df), index=temp_df.index)
year_rows = temp_df[1].str.contains('year', case=False).fillna(False)  # getting the rows which has year
temp_df.loc[(year_rows) & (temp_df[0]>=55), 0] = np.nan  # converting exp value to nan where value is >= 55 and unit is year
multiplier[year_rows] = 12
df['experience_in_months'] = temp_df[0] * multiplier
df
```

[image]